# How to add logging in scala code in databricks?

Tags: scala, logging, apache-spark-sql, log4j, azure-databricks

I know that on databricks we get the following cluster logs.

1. stdout
2. stderr
3. log4j

Just like how we have sl4j logging in java, I wanted to know how I could add my logs in the scala notebook.

I tried adding the below code in the notebook. But the message doesn't get printed in the log4j logs.

```
import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("TheLoggerName"))
logger.debug("****************************************************************** Useful message....")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you create your cluster in databricks, there is a tab where you can specify the log directory (empty by default).

Logs are written on DBFS, so you just have to specify the directory you want.

[image]

[image]

You can use like the code below in Databricks Notebook.

```
// creates a custom logger and log messages
var logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())
logger.debug("this is a debug log message")
logger.info("this is a information log message")
logger.warn("this is a warning log message")
logger.trace("this is a TRACE log message")
```

See [How to overwrite log4j configurations on Azure Databricks clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/clusters/overwrite-log4j-logs)